# Java IO with a Jar file using command line

Tags: java, jar, console

I want to be able to open a jar file and have it open a console that I can interact with it from. I have tried opening the jar with `java.exe` instead of `javaw.exe`, but the window that appears closes almost instantly when I try to run the program. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by 'open a jar'? Read the content of the jar file, or execute the class it contains as a Java application? Like 'java -jar jarname.jar' ?

Comment: Define "interact with". Do you want to be able to let your jar read input from user via console?

Comment: @KevinHooke I want to execute it as a Java application

Comment: @Pshemo I want to be able to interact with it as I normally would in NetBeans or Eclipse, but through a console since it is compiled into a Jar file

Comment: does it have a Manifest file or do you provide your main class? What's in your `main` method? Isn't it possible, that your application finishes its job, and end normally?

Comment: @NagyVilmos I am asking for user input that I never get prompted to enter. Also, nothing is being printed to the console before it is closed

Comment: I don't understand your question. What happens if you open your console application (for example cmd.exe) and then execute 'java -jar jarname.jar' as @KevinHooke suggested?

Comment: Open a command line first, then run it from the command line with 'java -jar jarname.jar' (assuming it as a main class in your manifest.mf) or 'java -cp jarname.jar classname ' and see what output you get. Otherwise, give us some more specifics on what it is that your code does and what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @yobrobob dou you have a manifest file? how did you packed that jar file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you run java.exe not from the console.
2. the program jar cannot be run, has errors, or exited immediately.
3. to run java.exe on Windows OS requires to create a surrogate console to run a console program.
4. javaw.exe doesn't open a console, so you can't see the output.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is closed because it is not waiting for input data.

See example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
    System.out.println("Hello! I'm waiting for input...");
    args = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split(" ");            
    System.out.println("I received your data: \r\n\r");
    for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++) System.out.print(args[i] + " ");
    System.out.println("\r\n\rAfter 10 second I'll close");
    Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
    // Here program did not waiting for input and was closed automatically;
}
```

What shown in console:

```
C:\Users\user>java -jar "C:\myprogram.jar"
Hello! I'm waiting for input...
bla blabla bla bla // I did enter it to console
I received your data:

bla blabla bla bla
After 10 second I'll close
```

After 10 seconds program was closed, because not waiting for input data.